# In ipython notebook, can't hide table borders as usual

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook

The following IPython notebook cell results in a table with a gray background and borders:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
s="""
<style type="text/css">
  table, td { 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    }
  </style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a
    <td>b
  <tr>
    <td>c
    <td>d
  </table>
"""
h = HTML(s); h
```

but when the same html content (the content of string s) is the entire body of a plain html file, the table has a gray background and no border (as intended). It appears that the border properties don't work correctly in IPython notebook. Any ideas?

Another puzzle: adding a colgroup to the table and a col to the css selector causes everything but the horizontal rule between rows to disappear in IPython notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `<style>` element without the (HTML5) `scoped` attribute appears in the `<body>` of an html document, the behavior of the agent is unspecified.

Browsers like Firefox and Opera try to do something anyway, but we can't be sure of the way [inheritance, cascading and specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) are accounted for in this fuzzy context.

You have two easy (local) solutions:

- add the `scoped` attribute (works well in Firefox, not so well in Opera, don't know about IE)

  `<style type="text/css">` --> `<style type="text/css" scoped>`

  The `scoped` attribute is subject to hot debate, see these for example: [On the abominable proposed html5 scoped attribute](http://www.webdirections.org/blog/on-the-abominable-proposed-html5-scoped-attribute-for-style-elements/) and [Saving the day with scoped CSS](http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/).
- and of course, [add an inline style](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.2) to your `<table>` element

Other, more global solutions aren't so good, in my opinion, but it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the problem. I put the style element in the body (without thinking much) because I don't know how to access the head, where I would have put it. I am experimenting with IPython notebook as a way to generate web pages, but maybe more conventional tools are more suitable.

Answer (score 4):

This will remove border from the whole table:
create and run a code cell above the table markdown cell, with the following content:

```
%%html
<style>
table,td,tr,th {border:none!important}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use inline css

```
<table style="border-style:hidden;border-collapse:collapse;">
```